# android - (Unfortunately program has stopped) in pushing a button twice

Tags: android

I'm writing a calculator for android.

I created a button for sqrt // button id: btn[11]

a TextView for holding the number // id: cNumber

and a double type variable for storing the sqrt of the number.(sqrtHolder)

[This is program picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6LiT.png)

code for btn[11]:

```
btn[11].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        sqrtHolder = Math.sqrt(Integer.parseInt(cNumber.getText().toString()));
        cNumber.setText(String.valueOf(sqrtHolder));
    }
});
```

now if user push sqrt button the result will print but if user push that button again program will crash and close.
Why ?

Comment: What is the error output? You should post your stacktrace so we can see exactly what went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

> now if user push sqrt button the result will print but if user push
>   that button again program will crash and close. Why ?

`Math.sqrt` returns a double. The first time you press on the button the TextView is probably filled up with an integer. After you press the button it contains a `double` (its `String.valueOf` ), and you can't use `Integer.parseInt` with double values